# Angularjs ui router keep url on wrong address

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, redirect

I have a standard module config like this:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: "/home",
            templateUrl: "templates/partials/home.html"
        })

        ...

        .state('error',{
            url: "/404",
            templateUrl: "templates/partials/404.html"
        });
});
```

And I need not to *redirect* to the 404.html page, but keep in the address bar the url which user tried go to.

Is there a simple method to reach that?

Answer (score 0):

Url is an optional field in state, if you don't add that , it will only render the template.

Try this :

```
.state('error',{
        templateUrl: "templates/partials/404.html"
    });
```

And add this state to otherwise